# MongoDB ignoring dbPath in config file

Tags: mongodb

I'm setting up a fresh centOS 7 install following these instructions.
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/

Using systemctl start mongod I get a error saying /data/dbs does not exist (which it doesn't). If I run

`sudo mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf`

Everything seems to work. I don't really want to edit the init script if I can avoid it, but is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution has ended up just being a new service which calls mongod with the parameters I want. I've disabled the default mongod service

`systemctl disable mongod`

Added my service file to /etc/systemd/system and enabled it

`systemctl enable my-mongod`

It works well enough and shouldn't be broken by updates as they come down. The only thing that threw me for a bit is that the service had to be of type forking for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing using `yum` in CentOS7 by using the repository file described in [Configure MongoDB v3.0 yum](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/#configure-the-package-management-system-yum), the MongoDB instance stores its data files in `/var/lib/mongo` and its log files in `/var/log/mongodb` by **default**, and runs using the `mongod` user account.

the default config should contain a section similar to:

```
storage:
    dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
    journal:
        enabled: true
```

Make sure whether there's no modification made to the content of your `/etc/mongod.conf`.